# 2-factor authenticated Google account and Trello on iPhone?

Tags: gmail, google, trello

I got an application-specific password, but I couldn't log in with it from Trello. Is there a way to not have to log into Trello every time I use the app?

I wouldn't mind making a Trello-specific account if that would fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

All theses app-specific passwords are for one-time use.

Trello app should remember the one-time password, authenticate with it and then should stay signed in. If it ever logs you out, you have to regenerate another app-specific password and then sign in with it again. Check if it's signing you out. If there is a "remember me" option, use it.

Answer (score 0):

The application specific password should be asked after the initial login. I suspect the integration with Google 2 factor auth is broken in the Trello iphone application. I have the same issue where the Trello application would keep denying access. I have tried the application specific password but it immediately asks for the account username/password.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself to see if it's a valid assumption?